# How to split a long string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

How to edit this string and split it into two?

```
 String asd = {RepositoryName: CodeCommitTest,RepositoryId: 425f5fc5-18d8-4ae5-b1a8-55eb9cf72bef};
```

I want to make two strings.

```
String reponame;
String RepoID;
```

reponame should be CodeCommitTest
repoID should be 425f5fc5-18d8-4ae5-b1a8-55eb9cf72bef

Can someone help me get it? Thanks

Comment: What is it that you have tried?. Also, if you are getting a JSON, then its probably good to use a JSON parser

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar JSON requires quote marks around everything.

Comment: @vinod I have never used JSON parser before any links to tutorials? I tried splitting but it didnt work

Comment: @ajb - I have seen cases where people are actually parsing a JSON but post "almost string representations". So, worth telling the OP don't you think?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/ Check this link for json parse.

Comment: @user2775042 - Are you getting data in JSON format?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar no, its a string

Comment: @user2775042 Is the _string_ you are getting in JSON format?

Comment: @ajb no, it looks exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Java code using a regular expression in case you can't use a JSON parsing library (which is what you probably should be using):

```
String pattern = "^\\{RepositoryName:\\s(.*?),RepositoryId:\\s(.*?)\\}$";
String asd = "{RepositoryName: CodeCommitTest,RepositoryId: 425f5fc5-18d8-4ae5-b1a8-55eb9cf72bef}";
String reponame = "";
String repoID = "";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(asd);
if (m.find()) {
    reponame = m.group(1);
    repoID = m.group(2);
    System.out.println("Found reponame: " + reponame + " with repoID: " + repoID);
} else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

This code has been tested in IntelliJ and runs without error.

**Output:**

```
Found reponame: CodeCommitTest with repoID: 425f5fc5-18d8-4ae5-b1a8-55eb9cf72bef
```

Comment: @Tim I get invalid escape sequence error - valid ones are \b \t

Comment: @user2775042 I just updated my answer, sorry.  It should work now :-)

Comment: @user2775042 - This code will work after the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there aren't quote marks in the input, and that the repository name and ID consist of letters, numbers, and dashes, then this should work to get the repository name:

```
Pattern repoNamePattern = Pattern.compile("RepositoryName: *([A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)");
Matcher matcher = repoNamePattern.matcher(asd);
if (matcher.find()) {
    reponame = matcher.group(1);
}
```

and you can do something similar to get the ID.  The above code just looks for `RepositoryName:`, possibly followed by spaces, followed by one or more letters, digits, or hyphen characters; then the `group(1)` method extracts the name, since it's the first (and only) group enclosed in `()` in the pattern.

Comment: Tim's answer will also work if the two fields are always in this order and there are no other fields in the input.  Mine is a little more flexible but uses two pattern matches.  Also, with my solution, you could put the above code in a method to avoid duplicate code.